# Longest line using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Can someone show, how to use awk command to identify the longest line in a text file.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'identify'?  Determine its length?  Determine its content?  Determine its record number?  All of the above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Longest line in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655372/longest-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 9):

To print the longest line:

```
awk 'length > m { m = length; a = $0 } END { print a }' input-file
```

To simply identify the longest line by line number:

```
awk 'length > m { m = length; a = NR } END { print a }' input-file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ if (length($0) > longest) longest = length($0); } END { print longest }'
```