# Using bash, how can I get the longest line in a file?

Tags: bash

Using bash, how can I get the longest line in a file?

```
$ cat file
12
3241234
123
3775
874
62693289429834
8772168376123
```

I want to get `62693289429834`.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607776/longest-line-using-awk

Comment: This is not a duplicate, since he's asking about 1. using bash and 2. getting the line, not the length.

Answer (score 2):

```
 sort -V file | tail -n1
```

works on your example input. I'm not completely sure it will work on other inputs as well but I think so.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk ' { if ( length > x ) { x = length } }END{ print x }' file
```