# How to find the longest column(hence line) in csv file in linux?

Tags: shell, unix, csv, awk

I have a csv file which contains millions of rows. Now few of the rows contains more data then column data type can accommodate. For e.g. csv file has only two rows as shown below please not ^_ is delimiter

```
A^_B^_C
AA^_BB^_CC
```

Now assume each line can accomodate only one character so line 1 row 1 is correct but line 2 is not and I want to find out all these kinds of lines.

So I thought if I get the longest lines from csv file I will be good and I tried to following but is not helping (from [longest line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655372/longest-line-in-a-file))

```
wc -L file
```

Please help me find the largest line/column in a csv file. Another problem is I have two delimiter so cant use cut command also.

Comment: What two delimiters you have? I only see `,` in sample data.

Comment: Hi @jaypal please see edited question with delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
awk '
{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
    if (length($i) == good) { continue } 
    else {
        print "Row "NR" contained data more than " good" in a single field"
        next
    }
    print "Row "NR " is valid"
}' FS='\\^_' good="1" csv
Row 1 is valid
Row 2 contained data more than 1 in a single field
```

**Explanation:**

- We set the Field Separator to `\\^_` (note we need to escape ^ since it is a special character).
- We iterate over each field
- We check the length of the field with the variable (`good`) passed at run time.
- If the field is good, we continue the loop to the next field and continue to do so until the last field of the row.
- If any field has a size greater than `good` we print our message with row number using `NR`.
- If all the fields are good then we print the message stating row is good.

If I misunderstood your question, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: hi thanks a lot for the answer. for sake of simplicity I said only one length for each column but length is variable I dont length of all columns. I just want that longest column should be visible in my output or longest line with culprits.

Comment: How do you define the longest column if you don't know what length to compare it with? If my acceptable length is say 10, I will report 11, 1000, 40000 and longest. You can just do `awk '{print "Row "NR" is "length($0)" characters"}' FS='\\^_' csv` to print length of each rows.

Comment: +1 this is pretty good answer for a not-so-well-defined problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'\\^_' -v OFS=':' '
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if (length($i) > max) {
            max = length($i)
            lineNr = NR
            line   = $0
            fldNr  =  i
            fld    = $i
        }
    }
}
END {
    print lineNr, line
    print fldNr, fld
}
' file
```

Comment: +1: Now that I see your answer, the question has become more clear. Ironic, isn't it? `:P`

Comment: Without the OP posting his expected output, we're all just guessing.

Comment: True, but I hate the fact that you always end up making the best guess! `;)`

Comment: That remains to be seen... Depends what `the largest line/column` means: the longest field, the line containing the longest field, the longest line, all the fields from the field number containing the longest field, or something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that requires defining the column lengths in a single line file using the same delimiter as the data ( assuming different columns can have different acceptable lengths ):

```
1^_1^_1
```

Using that file (which I called `clengths`) and using `split()` in an lazy way to get indexed elements:

```
awk -F'\\^_' '

  NR==FNR {split($0,clen,FS); next} # store the lengths

  {
    split($0,a,FS); # put the current line in an array
    for( i in a )
    { if( length(a[i]) > clen[i] ) print "["FNR","i"] = "a[i] }
  }
' clengths data
```

This outputs array styled indexes for the long data as `[row, col]` aka `[line #, field #]` starting at `[1,1]`:

```
 [2,1] = AA
 [2,2] = BB
 [2,3] = CC
```

Everything in the output is "too big" and is indexed to make finding it again easier.