# Why getting Memory Error? Python

Tags: python

I have a 5gb text file and i am trying to read it line by line. 
My file is in format-: Reviewerid<\t>pid<\t>date<\t>title<\t>body<\n>
This is my code

```
o = open('mproducts.txt','w')
with open('reviewsNew.txt','rb') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        line = line.strip()
        line2 = line.split('\t')
        o.write(str(line))
        o.write("\n")
```

But i get Memory error when i try to run it. I have an 8gb ram and 1Tb space then why am i getting this error? I tried to read it in blocks but then also i get that error.

```
MemoryError
```

Comment: How long is the longest line in that file?

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo I dont know. But when i try to open that file in EmEditor then a pop up window comes that "it contains some very large lines. Do you want to open it in binary format." By choosing binary option it displays the file correctly.

Comment: What is `o` in `o.write()`? If you are keeping everything that you read in memory, I am not surprised that you are getting a memory error.

Comment: Mode 'rb' opens the file in binary mode.  Try 'r+'.  See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Instead of reading line by line read in fixed size chunks. That way the line size wont matter.

Comment: @PaulRooney  How can i read it in chunks?

Comment: You pass a size argument to `read` e.g. `f1.read(1024)` reads on kb. Then you can just write that to the output file (I presume thats what it is) and read the next chunk. So therefore you wouldn't use `for line in f1:` instead use `f1.read(<size>)` and loop until you get a read of size 0.

Comment: @Akavall i edited my question. o is writing every line read in a file which i need later.

Comment: @PaulRooney i cannot read it like this because my file is in format-: <Reviewerid><\t><pid><\t><date><\t><title><\t><body><\n> . If i will read it in chunks then my last line of each chunk might not be in this format.

Comment: Why don't you add a log line that displays the length of each line and number of the line, then you will see where it breaks. It might be that your whole file is just one big line.

Comment: @Akavall How to add a log line? Sorry i am new to Python. Also my file is in the format described above.

Comment: You can just print. For example: `print (len(line))`

Comment: If you are on linux, you can do `wc -l your_file` in the terminal, to see how many lines you have in your file.

Comment: I@Akavall i know the number of lines is 30,71,800.

Comment: What about the longest line. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655372/longest-line-in-a-file) would help?

Comment: @PaulRooney while printing length , it prints length of all the lines but gives memory error. So how will i get to know at which line it broke?

Comment: Use `for i, line in enumerate(f1):` and print `i` on each iteration. The last one you see printed should be the last good line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Installing 64 bit Python solves the issue.

OP was using 32 bit Python that's why getting into memory limitation.

---

Reading whole comments I think this can help you.

- You can't read file in chunk (as 1024) since you want to process data.
- Instead, read file in chunk of lines i.e N lines at a time.
- You can use [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) keyword and [itertools](https://pymotw.com/2/itertools/) in Python to achieve above.

***Summary*** : Get N lines at time, process it and then write it.

**Sample Code :**

```
from itertools import islice
#You can change num_of_lines
def get_lines(file_handle,num_of_lines = 10):
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(file_handle, num_of_lines))
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        yield next_n_lines


o = open('mproducts.txt','w')

with open('reviewsNew.txt','r') as f1:
    for data_lines in get_lines(f1):
        for line in data_lines:
            line = line.strip()
            line2 = line.split('\t')
            o.write(str(line))
            o.write("\n")
o.close()
```

Comment: But i was reading line by line. I wasn't keeping anything in memory. I read one line and wrote it to another file. Also my largest line length will be around 9000. Is length the issue?

Comment: I don't think it line length issue. I just tried with line length10000. It works fine. Did my code help you?

Comment: Also, let me know if you are using windows or linux ?

Comment: What about Windows or linux?

Comment: Also, open command prompt and type "python" and hit enter. You will see the line like - Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32 -. Pleas tell me what is coming in your case?

Comment: Need to check whether you are using 32 bit python or 64 bit python?

Comment: your code didn't give memory error. But it wrote only first 13 lines. I have windows 10.

Comment: Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: Got it. MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel) -- It means you are using 32 bit python. 32 bit application can use 2^32 bit (4 GB) memory only. If your code is trying to use more than that then you will get MemoryError. Please install 64 bit python (2.7.12) and then try your code only. It might solve your problem.

Comment: But i installed python yesterday only :( it was the latest version 64 bit

Comment: I installed 2.7.12 only which is there on the main website.

Comment: I am not able to find python for 64 bit. There website just shows the download option. It doesn't show for which version i have to install.

Comment: Did you download it from first home page which has two buttons - 2.7.12 and 3.5?

Comment: Go to this link - https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/

Comment: Search - Windows x86-64 MSI installer - Download it and Uninstall previous version and install it.

Comment: It has a lot of versions. Which version should i download?

Comment: Windows x86-64 MSI installer

Comment: Uninstall previous version and install it

Comment: Any success ?? :)

Comment: You were so right. I installed 64 bit and it worked. Thank you so much ;)

Comment: I would upvote the answer but i am not allowed to do that as my points are less than 15 :P. But thank you so much :)

Comment: No issues. The good point is it works and you learned memory limitation of 32 bit applications :) :)

Comment: Yes since it was 32 bit so it could use only 4GB.But my code was reading line by line so it didn't require that much memory. So why was i getting that error?

Comment: The reason is that `for ... in somefile:` copies all file contents to memory