# UNIX tool - maximum row size of a csv file

Tags: csv, unix, size

I have a .csv file with a 236 columns that are all text based.

How do I find the row with largest size in bytes?

If I have a csv file in the following format:

```
   x,        y,       z
1  'hello', 'world', 
2  'quick', 'brown', 'fox'
3  'chick', 'fil',   'a'
```

How can I scan through this file to see which row has the largest size?

Expected result:

```
3 Size - 'x' bytes
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is more suited to another Stack Exchange site. Here's an answer from [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24509/how-to-print-the-longest-line-in-a-file

Comment: Or if you just need the length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655372/longest-line-in-a-file

Comment: Or I'm misinterpreting your question...do you want the size of a single column within the row? If those links above don't help you, please edit your question to clarify, with example input and output data (please limit it to a minimum number of lines to explain).

Comment: I have added additional detail.