# Find and print the biggest word with a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep

I currently have a log file and I have to filter the information to get the longest word ending in several characters using the "grep" command.

For example, I have to find the words ending in "abc".

And I have the following file:

```
XXXXXabc
YYabc
ZZZdef
XXabc
```

The correct output should be:

```
XXXXXabc
```

Until now I had tried with the following:

```
grep -E '\abc' log.txt | wc -L
```

But this returns the maximum length without showing the word.
How can I make the word print on the screen?

Thank you!

Comment: See: [... | awk '{print length, $0}' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 2-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655488/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -E \abc log.txt | awk '{print length($1) " " $1}' | sort -n |  tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

The idea: find the length, sort as number and then from last line print only the 2nd element.

Comment: Would be better if your code reflects your description: put the `tail` before the `awk`, so `awk` only have to process one line instead of the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

With a single awk command you can get it:

```
awk 'BEGIN {global_max = 0} /abc$/ {cur_max=length($0); if (cur_max > global_max) {global_max=cur_max; word=$0}} END {print word}' log.txt
```

Use a variable `global_max` that will keep track of the longest seen word (initialize to zero in the `BEGIN` block).

Then, for every line that ends in "abc", get the length and compare it to the maximum global length. If this is greater, substitute the old values for the new ones.

Finally, print the found word.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sort` will run slower (complexity `O(n log n)`). You should only visit each element once like the following (complexity `O(n)`:

```
maxSize=0; maxWord=""; while read -r LINE; do if [[ ${#LINE} -gt $maxSize ]]; then maxSize=${#LINE}; maxWord="${LINE}"; fi; done < input.txt; echo "$maxWord"
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep can't do that alone but with awk :

```
awk '/abc$/{m=length($0)>length(m)?$0:m}END{print m}' infile
```