# Alias bash one line script

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I have to do an alias called for example "longest" for this script:

```
data=""; len=0; line=""; while [[ $line != "quit" ]]; do read line; [[ $line != "quit" ]] && [[ ${#line} -gt len ]] && len=${#line} data=$line; done; echo $len; echo $data 1>2
```

Its job is simply reading words or phrases and counting the characters.

I put the script inside quotes like this:

```
alias longest="...script..."
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Can anyone explain to me why? A possible solution?

Comment: Why dont you simply write a script, make it executable and call it?

Comment: This absolutely should not be an alias.  But, as a first attempt, try just using single quotes: `alias longest=' ... '`

Comment: That should be a function.

Comment: Did you really mean to send output to a file named "2"? If you're trying to send output to stderr, use `1>&2` (or just `>&2`) rather than `1>2`. Also, there are a bunch of things in there that really should be double-quoted to avoid parsing weirdness. Finally, I'd recommend stopping on end-of-file as well as/instead of when getting "quit" (you could use `while read line && [[ $line != "quit" ]]; do ...` to check for either).

Answer (score 2):

You have several options (and I'm repeating the script from the question, not fixing any other errors (?) like redirecting to a file with name `2`):

1. Have the alias define a function and execute it immediately

   ```
   alias longest='f() { data=""; len=0; line=""; while [[ $line != "quit" ]]; do read line; [[ $line != "quit" ]] && [[ ${#line} -gt len ]] && len=${#line} data=$line; done; echo $len; echo $data 1>2; }; f'
   ```
2. Create a script and save it in a directory from your `PATH`, usually `~/bin`:

   File `~/bin/longest`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   data="";
   len=0;
   line="";
   while [[ $line != "quit" ]]; do
      read line;
      [[ $line != "quit" ]] && [[ ${#line} -gt len ]] && len=${#line} data=$line;
   done;
   echo $len;
   echo $data 1>2
   ```

   and finally `chmod +x ~/bin/longest`.
3. Define the function in your `.bashrc` file and then call it on demand.
4. Avoid the complicated, home-grown code and go for [something much simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655488/112968). The behavior and output will not be identical, but should be sufficient.

   ```
   alias longest="awk '{print length, \$0}' | sort -nr | head -1"
   ```

Comment: Why wrap a function in an alias instead of just defining & using the function it directly? Wrapping it in an alias just seems like useless complexity (& opportunity for parsing confusion). Speaking of which, in the `awk` version, you need to escape the `$` to keep `$0` from being expanded (since it's in double-quotes as the alias is being defined).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for the hint, I have fixed the awk example. As for why a function in an alias? Because the question was asking for a way to do this with an alias. I provided other options to suggest different solutions that do not necessarily involve a (complicated) alias.