# Can not read file in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

i downloaded a file from UNCTAD and unzip then i read using data.table package

https://unctadstat.unctad.org/7zip/US_TradeMatrix_Part5.csv.7z

```
temp <- data.table::fread("US_TradeMatrix_Part5_ST202209201450_v1.csv", 
      drop = c("US dollars at current prices in thousands Footnote", "Flow"), 
      check.names = TRUE, showProgress = TRUE)
```

I get the following error
`R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes`
please advise.

Comment: Could be a separator while reading the csv file . Use sep= "|" (or one of . or , depending on the separator used in your file. Also check the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438305/r-character-strings-are-limited-to-231-1-bytes-error-while-trying-to-load-txt for further suggestions

Comment: it could have something to do with it being a 2.6 GB csv file (just saying)

Comment: @Imitation the delimiter is `,`, but I think `fread` can handle it

Comment: @Mohamed what happens if you set the number of rows read to be smaller than all of them (i.e. running it with `nrows = 100`) ?

Comment: if i use sep = "|", it give me 1 variable only, if i use sep = "," it give me 9 variables

Comment: if i pass nrows = 1e4 and 
if i use sep = "|", it give me 1 variable only, 
if i use sep = "," it give me 9 variables. 
however i read the whole file with sep = "," or sep = "|", i get the same error

Comment: @Mohamed how much RAM is in your computer?

Comment: Mohamed, `fread` works as-is without needing to change `sep=` (in fact, changing it will likely fail in other ways, as you're discovering). The error does not evidence for me (see my answer) which suggests either you have a corrupted `.7z` download (seems less likely) or you need more RAM in your system. Since on my system the read-in object was over 13GB, that suggests to me that your computer needs ***MORE THAN*** 16GB of RAM to read it, since the OS and other running processes on your computer will almost certainly want/need more than a few GBs.

Answer (score 2):

The error is likely because your file does not have sufficient memory (RAM) to process it. I have 64GB of RAM, it took well over 6 minutes to read in the file, and the resulting object is over 13GB in R (the original file is over 20GB in size, uncompressed). I received no error.

Since it appears you cannot read that entire dataset into RAM at one time, I suggest you would benefit from alternative methods of getting at your data. None of these allow you to read all data into R: nothing you can do will allow that. (Technically, you can `select=` a subset of the columns to load in, but that assumes there are "large memory" columns you know you'll never use.)

1. Load into a database. One could use a "big server" DBMS such as postgres, mariadb, or sql server. Doing this is a lot more than "just R", outside the scope of this question. However, one might be able to use RSQLite or DuckDB (single-file databases). For instance, on the shell (not R):

   - SQLite: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

     ```bash
     $ sqlite3 US_TradeMatrix.sqlite3
     SQLite version 3.40.1 2022-12-28 14:03:47
     Enter ".help" for usage hints.
     sqlite> .mode csv
     sqlite> .import US_TradeMatrix_Part5_ST202306191712_v1.csv TradeMatrix
     ```
   - DuckDB: https://duckdb.org/docs/data/csv/overview.html

     (Note that the leading `D`  is the prompt string, not typed in by the user.)

     ```bash
     $ duckdb US_TradeMatrix.duckdb
     v0.8.1 6536a77232
     Enter ".help" for usage hints.
     D CREATE TABLE TradeMatrix (Year INT, YearLabel INT, Economy INT, EconomyLabel VARCHAR, Partner VARCHAR, ParnerLabel VARCHAR, Flow INT, FLowLabel VARCHAR, SitcRev3Product VARCHAR, SitcRev3ProductLabel VARCHAR, USdollars FLOAT, Footnote VARCHAR)
     D COPY TradeMatrix FROM 'US_TradeMatrix_Part5_ST202306191712_v1.csv' (AUTO_DETECT TRUE);
     ```

     I made guesses on the table schema, please verify.

   From here, one would use `DBI` and either `RSQLite` or `duckdb` to fashion SQL statements that reduce the data (and optionally do other things) before attempting to bring into R.
2. Lazy operations using `duckdb` on the CSV file itself, still requiring SQL. (Note that this might not be as fast as importing into a `duckdb` file as in #1 above. I haven't benchmarked it, but I cannot imagine random-access on CSV files would compare well with indexed database efficiencies.)

   ```r
   duck <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
   DBI::dbGetQuery(duck, "select * from 'US_TradeMatrix_Part5_ST202306191712_v1.csv' limit 10")
   #    Year Year Label Economy Economy Label Partner Partner Label Flow Flow Label SitcRev3Product                                    SitcRev3Product Label US dollars at current prices in thousands US dollars at current prices in thousands Footnote
   # 1  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports               0                                    Food and live animals                                1068138072                                               <NA>
   # 2  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports              00           Live animals other than animals of division 03                                  21120296                                               <NA>
   # 3  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports             001           Live animals other than animals of division 03                                  21120296                                               <NA>
   # 4  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports              01                               Meat and meat preparations                                 128581301                                               <NA>
   # 5  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports             011         Meat of bovine animals, fresh, chilled or frozen                                  39233046                                               <NA>
   # 6  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports             012                         Other meat and edible meat offal                                  66138000                                               <NA>
   # 7  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports             016    Meat, edible meat offal, salted, dried; flours, meals                                   4135049                                               <NA>
   # 8  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports             017     Meat, edible meat offal, prepared, preserved, n.e.s.                                  19075207                                               <NA>
   # 9  2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports              02                           Dairy products and birds' eggs                                  76369447                                               <NA>
   # 10 2016       2016    0000         World    0000         World   01    Imports             022 Milk, cream and milk products (excluding butter, cheese)                                  37031756                                               <NA>
   ```
3. Lazy operations with `arrow`, using `dplyr` as the language:

   ```r
   tradematrix <- arrow::open_csv_dataset("US_TradeMatrix_Part5_ST202306191712_v1.csv")
   tradematrix %>%
     head(n=10) %>%
     collect()
   # # A tibble: 10 × 12
   #     Year `Year Label` Economy `Economy Label` Partner `Partner Label`  Flow `Flow Label` SitcRev3Product `SitcRev3Product Label`                                  `US dollars at current prices in thousands` US dollars at current prices…¹
   #    <int>        <int>   <int> <chr>           <chr>   <chr>           <int> <chr>        <chr>           <chr>                                                                                          <dbl>                          <???>
   #  1  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      0               Food and live animals                                                                    1068138072.                              .
   #  2  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      00              Live animals other than animals of division 03                                             21120296.                              .
   #  3  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      001             Live animals other than animals of division 03                                             21120296.                              .
   #  4  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      01              Meat and meat preparations                                                                128581301.                              .
   #  5  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      011             Meat of bovine animals, fresh, chilled or frozen                                           39233046.                              .
   #  6  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      012             Other meat and edible meat offal                                                           66138000.                              .
   #  7  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      016             Meat, edible meat offal, salted, dried; flours, meals                                       4135049.                              .
   #  8  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      017             Meat, edible meat offal, prepared, preserved, n.e.s.                                       19075207.                              .
   #  9  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      02              Dairy products and birds' eggs                                                             76369447.                              .
   # 10  2016         2016       0 World           0000    World               1 Imports      022             Milk, cream and milk products (excluding butter, cheese)                                   37031756.                              .
   # # ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`US dollars at current prices in thousands Footnote`
   ```

   This method supports most of `dplyr`s verbs, and many base R functions within `mutate` and `summarize`.

Comment: I contacted UNCTAD and they requested to download the file again. Problem is solved. However I would like to thank you specially r2evans for directing me to arrow package.